# Upcoming birthday list in views, based on birth date

Tags: views, datetime

In Drupal 8
I created some extra fields at "user", such as date of birth" (dd-mm-yyyy)
I want to show in a block in views the upcoming birthdays.
BUT...I can't sort them on date, because the order takes also the year!
How to make a birthdaylist in Drupal 8 bases on the day of birth, regardless the year.
Can you do it this way, or are there more ways to display an upcoming birthday list?
Thank you all!

Comment: What I would do it to create a new event content type with a recurring date field. Then using Rules, whenever a user creates/updates his profile I will create/update the event.

Comment: However I have to dive in that rule, I think it is a brilliant Idea. If I get stuck by creating this rule, I can always make an seperate content type "birthdays", based on the recurring events. Great! The only thing is to delete birthday on that content-type when user is deleted or deactivated. I hope I can do it by your suggestion. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome :) if you need help with the rule you're creating please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly let you know!